# Create new category listing page in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new to magento. In my project I am showing only 10 products of each category in category page. Now i want to show all the products of that category in another page. I dont know where to start. Can someone help me here??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are after displaying a listing in a CMS page via admin, you could just use the following:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" 
  category_id="your_category_id" 
  template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. I tried this.. Its working when i enter category id manually.. but for dynamic case???

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic case??

Comment: I mean how to pass category id to that block??

Comment: Why you are unable to check the ID of the category and then just type it in?? Refer to: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

Comment: It is possible for one category as mentioned there. But i want to show separate page for all my categories..

Comment: So, you would like to list all products on one page? Or list all category names on one page?

Comment: Sorry i think i have confused you.. I have changed my categories landing page (Shows recent 10 products). Now i want another page for each category where i can show remaining products of that category.. Hope you get it.. Sorry for my english.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16036/discussion-between-merca-and-itdeeps)

Answer (score 0):

If its going to be exactly like the category page, couldn't you just allow a view all in the magento admin (CATALOG > ALLOW ALL PRODUCTS PER PAGE) and then create the page dynamically appending ?limit=all at the end of your url?

Comment: Actually design completely changes for first 10 and remaining so i cant show those in same page..